# gitlab CI pipeline build job is not accessing dependencies from git's local m2repo

Tags: git, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, artifactory

I have a maven project in gitlab and I am creating a Gitlab CI pipeline to build the project.
As per my understanding, when we build the maven project, it will download the dependencies from artifactory and store it in m2repo. (local repository)
Also when build the project, each and every time it will check whether the dependency is available in local or not. If it is available in local, it will simply consider that dependency available in local and will not find it in artifactory.
But if it is not available in local then it will access the dependency from artifactory.

My concern is that we are not having the same behaviour in gitlab.
In gitlab CI, when build job is triggered, it is not accessing the dependency from local repository.(even when it is present)
Whenever build job is triggered, each and every time dependencies gets downloaded from artifactory.
As per my understanding, it should first search for the dependency in git's local repo and then it should reach out to artifactory if dependency is not available in local repo.

Please let me know if anyone have any idea on this.

Comment: Use the functionality of [Cache dependencies in Gitlab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) This will allow to store downloaded dependencies so that they don’t have to be fetched from the internet again

Comment: Thanks Sourav. Mainly what I want to understand is what exactly we need to configure in our gitlab ci pipeline in order to pick the dependency directly from git's local repository (when it is already present) instead of downloading it from internet. I have seen that git has downloaded the dependency from internet and kept it in git's local m2repo at the time of build job. Please let me know that what is the use of git's local m2repo and where can I find it in gitlab.

Comment: Have you gone through the link I have provided in previous comment. Configure the cache dependency, wherein you need to add the path of the local m2repo from where dependencies will be fetch.